# winapi dialogbox doesn't show

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, dialog

I have the problem with my dialog, that when i invoke the function "DialogBoxA" the Dialog doesn't appear. I only get the "Busy Cursor" and the the cursor is also trapped inside of a small rectangle (the size of the dialog). After the press of (almost) any button it magically appears.

**Dialog box call**

```
DialogBoxA(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCEA(IDD_ORACLE_DIALOG),0,reinterpret_cast<DLGPROC>(DlgProc));
```

**Dialog resource code**

```
IDD_ORACLE_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 155, 71
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,43,50,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,98,50,50,14
    COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBOSERVER,53,6,94,30,CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_SORT | CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDITLOG,54,25,94,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    LTEXT           "Server",IDC_STATIC,7,7,47,13
    LTEXT           "Log",IDC_STATIC,7,25,47,13
END
```

**DialogProc**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){
    switch(Msg){
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        for(auto it = vServerList.begin();it!=vServerList.end();++it){
            SendMessageA(GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_COMBOSERVER),CB_ADDSTRING,0,reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(it->c_str()));
        }
        if(vServerList.size()>0){
            SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_COMBOSERVER),CB_SETCURSEL,0,0);
            SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_EDITLOG),WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,HTCAPTION,0);
        }else{
            SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_COMBOSERVER),WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,HTCAPTION,0);
        }
#ifdef _DEBUG
        SendMessageA(GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_EDITLOG),WM_SETTEXT,0,reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>("q40log"));
#endif
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(wParam){
        case IDOK:
            size_t tServer,tLog;
            tServer = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_COMBOSERVER))+1;
            tLog = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_EDITLOG))+1;
            char *pszServer,*pszLog;
            pszServer = static_cast<char*>(calloc(tServer,sizeof(char)));
            pszLog = static_cast<char*>(calloc(tLog,sizeof(char)));
            GetDlgItemTextA(hWndDlg,IDC_COMBOSERVER,pszServer,tServer);
            GetDlgItemTextA(hWndDlg,IDC_EDITLOG,pszLog,tLog);
            szServer = pszServer;
            szUser = pszLog;
            free(pszServer);
            free(pszLog);
            EndDialog(hWndDlg,0);
            return TRUE;
        case IDCLOSE:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hWndDlg,0);
            return FALSE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: `.RC` excerpt looks good, your `DlgProc` might be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious failure modes are:

1. The dialog procedure is faulty.
2. The dialog resource is invalid.
3. The dialog resource is linked incorrectly and so cannot be loaded.
4. The instance handle is incorrect.

Of these options, the cast that you used in the dialog procedure parameter, it seems very likely that the dialog procedure is faulty.

I expect that you added the cast because the code would not compile. And it would not compile because the dialog procedure has an incorrect signature. The cast does not change that fact. It is just a way for you to suppress the compiler and tell it that you know better than it does. Generally speaking, the compiler tends to be right. If your dialog procedure has the wrong signature you need to correct it. Refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx) to find out the correct signature.

The other big problem with your code is that you ignore the return value of `DialogBox`. If the function fails then the documentation tells you that a value of 0 or -1. In that scenario you can call `GetLastError` to get extended error information. You must get into the habit of checking for errors when using Win32 API functions.

Comment: I just checked and there is no error after the call of the Dialogbox function. of course i will update my question with my dialogproc so you get more of an idea what i did

Comment: That does not invalidate my advice which is that you must always check for errors. Your code in the Q did not. You must remedy that. You don't check for errors anywhere in your code. You simply have to do so. Option 1 looks like the cause of the problems. You also seem to be having some Unicode issues. You are compiling for UNICODE right? In which case, why are you calling ANSI APIs?

Comment: Insulting people that help you and give you advice is seldom likely to yield results. Good luck.

Comment: My apologies, this "seemingly" ordinary simple code was getting on my nerves for not working. Thanks to your input i found the mistake.

Comment: Your guess is correct, but it had nothing to do with the function signature. the part where I set the focus to either the combobox or the edit control caused this "weird" behavior.

Comment: Ok. But remember that when I wrote the answer I could not see the dialog proc. And invalid dialog proc can mean bad code inside as well as bad signature.